# Python gdalwarp incorrectly resample raster files

Tags: python-3.x, gdal

I am using gdalwarp of GDAL3.1.4 to resample a raster from (0.0125, 0.00833 degree) to (0.03125, 0.025 degree).
To do so, I used the following code

```
ds= gdal.Open("test.tif", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
xmin=118
xmax=150
ymin=20
ymax=48
ds.Res =gdal.Warp("Resample_test.tif", ds, xRes= 0.03125, yRes= 0.025, resampleAlg= "average",
              outputType=gdal.GDT_Float32, outputBounds=(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
```

I believe that the "average" resampling method would consider all contributing pixels (in this case 2.5 pixels in the longitude and 3 pixels in the altitude) and return the weighted average.
However, gdal.Warp returned "incorrect" values (as explained in the following figure)

[image: Example of raster resampling]

Does anyone  have an explanation ?
PS. Same problem occurred with GDAL3.3.1

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get a solution to this issue? I have a similar issue of using gdalwarp from GDAL2.2.2

Comment: Could not find a solution!
Instead, I used rio.reproject_match(). It gives correct results.
check here: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_array.RasterArray.reproject_match

Comment: Thanks for this, will try out rioxarray